# How to save persistent values in PHP and remove all the persistent values on tab close

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have an **calendar** application that does look like this:
[Calendar app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svF99.png).

The function I am implementing is the **navigation** through the months (previous month/next month) function.

During the implementation I have encountered a few problems:

1. PHP cannot easily persist variables.
2. Persistent values have to be deleted/removed when closing the tab/opening the page for the first time.

Adressing Issues
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opt8d.png). There are several ways to persist a variable:

**Starting a session**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["favcolor1"] = "green";
echo $_SESSION["favcolor1"];
```

Issues

1. The value persists, but the variables are nowhere to be found in the app memory.
2. When closing the tab, the value remains, which is a **problem**.

**Saving as cookie**

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "Hello World", time()+3600);
echo $_COOKIE["TestCookie"];
```

The variable can be found in the app storage

Issues

1. If there is an echo before setcookie, it will be cancelled, i.e. it will not be executed. (xDD).
2. When closing the tab, it persists, which is a **problem**.

Other possible solutions

1. External files, which should work with `include` and `define
2. Using a database to keep track of persistent variables.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opt8d.png). Tab close event can be done via JS with `beforeunload` ??
Is there a way to do it via PHP ?

The problem persists:

1. The variable should persist, which can be solved
2. The values should be cancelled when the tab is closed.

Comment: You're not being very clear about the difference between the web server, running PHP, and the client browser, running Javascript. Sessions are stored on the server, not the client, whereas cookies are stored on the client, not the server. Realizing that there are two clearly distinct domains where code can run, server-side and client-side, is the first step to solving the problem you're having.

Comment: ok an alternative question, how do you get/see the session variables ?

Comment: You've got the code for PHP in your question, so you can access it server-side. If you want to access the same variable client-side you have to send it from PHP to the browser, for instance by echoing it. However, there are many methods to do this. A common method to retrieve data with Javascript from the server is [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp). There is software to simplify AJAX calls, for instance [JQuery](https://jquery.com/), but most developers would now-a-days say [you don't need it anymore](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Lets say i do go the cookie route, how do i delete all the cookies after the respective tab is closed ?

Comment: If you don't set an expiry time for a cookie, then it will automatically be removed at the end of the "browsing session" - only that is usually when you close the browser window, not an individual tab. If you want something that is only set in the context of the current tab, and will be removed when the tab is closed, then you should look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage